# Can't find Openssl on Cygwin package list

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, openssl

Here it is said
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)

to install

```
devel → openssl 
libs → openssl-devel
```

But downloading latest cygwin I can only see libs → openssl-devel so where is openssl ?

Comment: ok they made a mistake in their doc it's in .net.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

1- Uncheck the absolute packages option.

2- Check if it is already installed in your cygwin path.

Answer (score 1):

You can find both of these packages just by typing `openssl` in the search box at top left in setup.exe.