# Error including Openssl header files using Cygwin on Netbeans

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, openssl, cygwin

I am trying to compile a C file that uses Openssl with Cygwin in Netbeans. I have added the include folder in the options folder. However, the compiler throws an error below. Do I need to do something extra to get the include files working.

```
gcc -m32 -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/client.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/client.o client.c
client.c:43:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

[image: Netbeans options]

Comment: Are you compiling with cygwin gcc or mingw64 one ? You can not mix the two things. Have you installed the openssl headers ?

Comment: I believe you need to include the "OpenSSL developer" package; and not just the OpenSSL libraries. See [Can't find Openssl on Cygwin package list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6394902). I also think its better to build OpenSSL from sources for Cygwin. Also see [“CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set” error on Cygwin-x64](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20801996/608639) and [Unable to compute a CMAC using Cygwin and OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35528975/608639).